# The inlined style added with jquery is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, styles

I count the listed items and depending on the number of items I add the inline style. However, the inline style shows up empty.

[image: Empty inlined style]

```
var liList = document.getElementById("reports-list").getElementsByTagName("li");
var listCount = liList.length;

if (listCount == 0) {
    $('#download-reports').css({'display': 'none !important'});
    $('#welcome-left').css({'width': '100% !important'});
} else if (listCount >= 1) {
    $('#download-reports').css({'display': 'block !important'});
    $('#welcome-left').css({'width': '65% !important'});
}
```

Comment: We need more context into when this logic is being ran, especially in relation to when the elements are being created on the page.

Comment: You can `console.log($('#download-reports').length)` in your logic and verify that it is finding the elements when the logic runs.

Comment: Actually your issue is most likely that you are trying to use `!important` inline.  jQuery isn't going to let you do that, as far as I'm aware.  You need to remove those

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `.css()` instead of `.hide()` and `.show()`?

Comment: There's no point in `else if (listCount >= 1)`. Just use `else`, since this is the only other possibility.

Comment: @Taplar there is no point check the length of `#download-reports` because that's the parent `div` that I am trying to hide depending on the length of the listed items. I printed the length of `listCount` and it shows 25. What I couldn't figure it out is why the `style` on the parent `div` is empty.

Comment: Printing the length of found elements is a first step in debugging that elements are being found by the logic.  It is a way of confirming assumptions, which is a requirement when debugging logic.  Many problems are caused by unintentionally accepting assumptions.

Comment: Apparently, it was happening because of a typo that I had on my code. I fixed that and also I changed `else if` to `else` and followed @TJBlackman's directions (created a class | added and removed it depending on the listCount.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that an inline style attribute is just that, an *attribute*! And jQuery gives us a method to change attributes. So you can do something like this.

`$('#div').attr('style','display: none !important;');`

**J[S Fiddle DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/dvfze5t9/3/)**

However, this wont add to what's already existing in the inline style, it will completely replace it. If the element does not have an inline style tag, this will create it, but if an inline style attribute already exists, this will completely replace it.

Also - this is probably not the best way to do it. What you probably should do is include a class to your css style sheet, and that class has your desired styles. Then just add or remove that class!

```
.master_hidden {
  display: none !important;
}

$('#div').addClass('master_hidden');
$('#div').removeClass('master_hidden');
```